# How to connect to ncbi databases for text search? MathIOmica authoring instructions now do not work

Tags: packages, web-access, databases

Mias's [suplementary material](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-319-72377-8_1)  in the notebook `MmaBioinfo_Ch4_Databases` contains a code for search the snp related to autism

```
URLExecute[
  "https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esearch.fcgi"
, { "RequestMethod" -> "POST", "retmode" -> "json", "db" -> "snp", "term" -> "autism"}
, "RawJSON"
]
```

with result

> ```
>  <|header -> <|type -> esearch, version -> 0.3|>
>  , esearchresult -> <|
>      count -> 30, retmax -> 20, retstart -> 0, idlist -> {386572987, 122468182, 121912597, 121908445, 104894663, 60754679, 60350369, 59359388, 58778612, 56567265, 52837965, 17851360, 17826777, 17551405, 17350302, 17295902, 10373747, 10348618, 10314229, 7794745}
>    , translationset -> {}, translationstack -> {<|term -> autism[All Fields], field -> All Fields, count -> 30, explode -> N|>, GROUP}
>    , querytranslation -> autism[All Fields]|>
> |>
> ```

But my results after executing the same code is really empty

> ```
> <| header -> <|type -> esearch, version -> 0.3|>
>  , esearchresult -> <|count -> 0, retmax -> 0, retstart -> 0, idlist -> {}
>  , translationset -> {}, querytranslation -> (autism[All Fields])
>  , errorlist -> <|phrasesnotfound -> {autism}, fieldsnotfound -> {}|>
>  , warninglist -> <|phrasesignored -> {}, quotedphrasesnotfound -> {}, outputmessages -> {No items found.}|>|>
> |>
> ```

i.e. without any successful search result

I think the database structure was changed between December 2017 and today. But how to change the query to take this change into account?

Comment: Is this really a Mathematica problem? Have you done a research about this db? Have you contacted authors?

Comment: I think it is. Firstly, URLExecute is a built-in function. Secondly, I hope that solution is a change of some values of parameters within URLExecute.
I think it will be very useful to understand the principles by which to guess the correct change of parameters after  the database changes

Comment: But URLExecture works well, it is the query which is out of date, the fix is to provide a correct query for your db, which has nothing to do with Mathematica. This problem is the same whether you use URLExecute or any other client. Or did I miss the point? p.s. there are no general principles to guess, an arbitrary db can e.g. vanish.

Comment: If you search snp directly, it returns [nothing](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/snp/?term=autism). I suggest you contact the author, email address is at the link you gave in your post.

Comment: Kuba: Yes, you're right, I am sorry. I've tried other database options and all work predictably except  `"snp"`

The same problem is observable at the http address level:

`https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esearch.fcgi?db=snp&term=autism`

vs.

`https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esearch.fcgi?db=nuccore&term=autism`

I still do not know where the problem is. But now I know it's not at Mathematica level, as I had previously thought.